# Typescript - restrict string values to enum values

Tags: typescript, enums

I want `role` to have one of these values: `ADMIN / USER / GUEST`.

I try to implement this using `enum`, however I get an error in the following minimal example:

```
enum EnumRole {
  ADMIN = 'ADMIN',
  USER = 'USER',
  GUEST = 'GUEST',
}

/* ------------------------------------------------- */

const role: EnumRole.ADMIN = 'ADMIN';
```

> Type '"ADMIN"' is not assignable to type 'EnumRole.ADMIN'.

[Check playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAouECUD2AbYUDeAoKUCCAIgLICSAclALxQDkhpZNANDlAKoDKMCVtn3zVgHE2MDgBVeNEWPGCAvliwB6AFRQAtFu07de-QcM6oq5UoDGSEAGcALlABOqYAC5Y8ZGgB09clN%20MANxAA)

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const role: EnumRole = EnumRole.ADMIN;`?

Comment: In my project, I can not alter the `role = 'ADMIN'` part. I can only change the enum model and/or the type assignment. How could it be done?

Comment: If you want to assign it from the string: `const role: EnumRole = EnumRole['ADMIN']`

Comment: This thread might be what you're looking for: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the role type as strong types,
you can do this as,

```
const role:'ADMIN' | 'USER' | 'GUEST' = 'ADMIN'
```

Now the type will be restricted within ADMIN/USER/GUEST. You don't need the `enum` in this case

Comment: Although enum is not needed, and out of curiosity, could I somehow restrict strings to enum values?

Comment: As far as i know, enum can't be use to set strong types.